# How to calculate the stabilization moment in a time-series (after one pronounced peak)?

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart, trend, trendline

I want to know when a time series stabilizes after its peak.

This time series shows a peak, and then it goes down (see images below (1); (2)).
I would like to calculate the moment at which this time-series stabilizes (becomes flatter) after its peak.

In an ideal world, the data should go down to 0 and stay there. But as you see, it does not reach 0, nor stay 100% stable.

I thought of various different ways/possibilities:

-Calculate a tangent point to see the slope change. But the data has many small ups & downs even after smoothing it.
-Calculate the average at the tail (end of the series /e.g. if time = 8000; calculate last 2000 values mean average), then calculate an interval (margin +- this value), then calculate the time at which the first value appears in this interval.
-Calculate pronounced changes in the trend or slope.

*Maybe you have a better idea I did not consider. Feel free to share it if you've already dealt with this in the past.

I need to know the time at which this stabilization happened.

Ideally, you could mute/ignore all values before the peak value, but without deleting these rows (time should stay). Calculating the peak is easy (max value).

I also standardized the data so it starts at y=0 (I have various time series, I make them all start at y=0 to compare them later*).

I do not know how to provide the data because it is about 8k values.
I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you very much.

[image: time series example]
[image: more depurated time series just in case, smoothened with "smooth.spline"]

Comment: I think a good answer would be informed by your domain knowledge about what stabilized means, and what the tradeoffs are between calling it too soon or not soon enough. It looks like a simple approach might be to look at a ~1000 point moving average and look for the first non-negative slope.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah. Eventually i dig deeper into the moving average and tail values. Indeed I will deepen in what stabilized means and the tradeoffs. Thank you. :)